# Cannot deploy contracts on Polygon Mumbai, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, polygon, deploy

I'm trying to deploy contracts to the Polygon Testnet Mumbai, but I get no confirmation, it works maybe 1 in a 50 attempts. I've been iterating my code and I'm quite confused as to what is going wrong.

My question is what am I doing wrong in the following gas estimate code.

Sometimes I get the "replacement price too low", how do I deal with that case and adjust nonce, gasLimit and gasPrice accordingly.

Any advice to make this process as reliable will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```typescript
import axios from "axios";
import { BigNumber, ethers } from "ethers";
import {
  getEnvExtraTipForMiners,
  getGasStationPriority,
} from "~/libs/utils/env.server";
import { WEB3_ERROR_TYPE } from "../error.server";
import { asyncGetProvider, getBigNumberFraction } from "../utils.server";

export enum GAS_STATION_PRIORITY {
  SAFE_LOW = "safeLow",
  STANDARD = "standard",
  FAST = "fast",
}

interface iGasEstimateInput {
  txObject: any;
  gasStation: string;
  authorityAddress: string;
}

interface iGasPriceTier {
  maxPriorityFee: number;
  maxFee: number;
}

interface iGasStationResponse {
  safeLow: iGasPriceTier;
  standard: iGasPriceTier;
  fast: iGasPriceTier;
  estimatedBaseFee: number;
  blockTime: number;
  blockNumber: number;
}

export interface iGasEstimate {
  blockNumber: number;
  estimatedGasUnits: string;
  adjustedGasUnits: string;
  maxFeePerGasInWei: string;
  maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei: string;
  minEtherRequiredInWei: string;
  authorityBalanceInWei: string;
  maxPossibleDeploys: string;
  remainderAfterMaxDeploys: string;
}

export const asyncGetTxGasEstimate = async ({
  txObject,
  gasStation,
  authorityAddress,
}: iGasEstimateInput): Promise<iGasEstimate> => {
  // const GAS_MULTIPLIER = getEnvGasMultiplier();
  // const PRICE_MULTIPLIER = getEnvPriceMultiplier();
  const GAS_MULTIPLIER = "6";
  const PRICE_MULTIPLIER = "2";
  const EXTRA_TIP_FOR_MINER = parseFloat(getEnvExtraTipForMiners());
  // const { denominator, numerator } = getBigNumberFraction(GAS_MULTIPLIER);
  const gasMultiplier = getBigNumberFraction(GAS_MULTIPLIER);
  const priceMultiplier = getBigNumberFraction(PRICE_MULTIPLIER);
  console.info({ gasMultiplier, priceMultiplier });

  const provider = await asyncGetProvider();

  const estimatedGasUnits = await provider.estimateGas(txObject.data);

  const adjustedGasUnits = estimatedGasUnits
    .mul(gasMultiplier.numerator)
    .div(gasMultiplier.denominator);

  const gasStationObj = await axios
    .get<iGasStationResponse>(gasStation)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      throw new Error(WEB3_ERROR_TYPE.GAS_STATION_UNAVAILABLE);
    });

  if (!gasStationObj) throw new Error(WEB3_ERROR_TYPE.GAS_STATION_UNAVAILABLE);

  const speed = getGasStationPriority(); // "standard","safeLow" or "fast"

  console.info({ using: speed, gasStationObj });

  let block_number = gasStationObj.blockNumber;
  let base_fee_in_gwei = gasStationObj.estimatedBaseFee;

  let max_priority_fee_in_gwei =
    gasStationObj[speed].maxPriorityFee + EXTRA_TIP_FOR_MINER;

  let max_fee_per_gas_in_gwei = base_fee_in_gwei + max_priority_fee_in_gwei;

  //  In case the network gets (up to 25%) more congested
  max_fee_per_gas_in_gwei += base_fee_in_gwei * 0.25;

  //  cast gwei numbers to wei BigNumbers for ethers
  const maxFeePerGasInWei = ethers.utils
    .parseUnits(max_fee_per_gas_in_gwei.toFixed(9), "gwei")
    .mul(priceMultiplier.numerator)
    .div(priceMultiplier.denominator);

  const maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei = ethers.utils
    .parseUnits(max_priority_fee_in_gwei.toFixed(9), "gwei")
    .mul(priceMultiplier.numerator)
    .div(priceMultiplier.denominator);

  const minEtherRequiredInWei = adjustedGasUnits
    .mul(maxFeePerGasInWei)
    .mul(priceMultiplier.numerator)
    .div(priceMultiplier.denominator);

  const authorityBalanceInWei = BigNumber.from(
    await provider.getBalance(authorityAddress)
  );

  const maxPossibleDeploys = authorityBalanceInWei.div(minEtherRequiredInWei);

  const remainderAfterMaxDeploys = authorityBalanceInWei.mod(
    minEtherRequiredInWei
  );

  const result = {
    blockNumber: block_number,
    estimatedGasUnits: estimatedGasUnits.toString(),
    adjustedGasUnits: adjustedGasUnits.toString(),
    maxFeePerGasInWei: maxFeePerGasInWei.toString(),
    maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei: maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei.toString(),
    minEtherRequiredInWei: minEtherRequiredInWei.toString(),
    authorityBalanceInWei: authorityBalanceInWei.toString(),
    maxPossibleDeploys: maxPossibleDeploys.toString(),
    remainderAfterMaxDeploys: remainderAfterMaxDeploys.toString(),
  };

  return result;
};
```

Output:

```json
{
  gasMultiplier: {
    numerator: BigNumber { _hex: '0x06', _isBigNumber: true },
    denominator: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true }
  },
  priceMultiplier: {
    numerator: BigNumber { _hex: '0x02', _isBigNumber: true },
    denominator: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true }
  }
}
{
  gasStationObj: {
    safeLow: { maxPriorityFee: 1.5549384506666668, maxFee: 1.5549384656666667 },
    standard: { maxPriorityFee: 1.5800977807333334, maxFee: 1.5800977957333333 },
    fast: { maxPriorityFee: 1.7721584534666668, maxFee: 1.7721584684666667 },
    estimatedBaseFee: 1.5e-8,
    blockTime: 2,
    blockNumber: 40890601
  }
}
{ using: 'fast' }
{
  gasEstimate: {
    blockNumber: 40890601,
    estimatedGasUnits: '53000',
    adjustedGasUnits: '318000',
    maxFeePerGasInWei: '3544316944',
    maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei: '3544316906',
    minEtherRequiredInWei: '2254185576384000',
    authorityBalanceInWei: '0',
    maxPossibleDeploys: '0',
    remainderAfterMaxDeploys: '0'
  }
}
```

Deploy Code:

```typescript
const deployContractV1 = async ({
  contractFactory,
  contractUri,
  certificateId,
  certificateName,
  authorityAddress,
  authorityName,
  gasEstimate,
  nonce,
}: iDeployContractV1Input) => {
  console.info({
    contractUri,
    certificateId,
    certificateName,
    authorityAddress,
    authorityName,
    // gasEstimate,
    nonce,
  });

  await asyncUpdateContractDeployed({
    certificate: certificateId,
    status: "running",
  });

  console.info("deploying contract...");
  try {
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(
      contractUri,
      certificateId,
      certificateName,
      authorityAddress,
      authorityName,
      {
        // gasPrice: gasEstimate.maxFeePerGasInWei, // or you can split the fees as per EIP-1559
        // maxPriorityFeePerGas: gasEstimate.maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei,
        // maxFeePerGas: gasEstimate.maxFeePerGasInWei,
        gasPrice: gasEstimate.maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei,
        // gasPrice: "253532695",
        gasLimit: gasEstimate.adjustedGasUnits, // Gas limit
        nonce: nonce, // Nonce
      }
    );

    console.log("Transaction hash:", contract.deployTransaction.hash);
    console.log("Contract address:", contract.address);

    await asyncUpdateContractDeployed({
      certificate: certificateId,
      status: "running",
      transactionHash: contract.deployTransaction.hash,
      contractAddress: contract.address,
    });

    const timeout = getTxTimeoutMinutes() * 60000;
    console.info({ setTimeout: timeout });
    // Wait for the transaction to be mined
    await Promise.race([
      contract.deployTransaction.wait(),
      deployTimeout(timeout, certificateId), // Set timeout to 60 seconds, or adjust as needed
    ]);

    console.log("Contract deployed successfully!");

    return await asyncUpdateContractDeployed({
      certificate: certificateId,
      status: "active",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (isError(error)) {
      if (error.message.includes("REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED")) {
        console.info({
          error: "REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED",
        });
        throw new Error("REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED");
      }
      console.info({
        error: error.message,
      });
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
    throw error;
  }
};
```